# Plots with a common x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data.frame df with columns `T` ,`V1`,`V2`,`V3`,`V4`
I would like to make a ggplot containing two plots with `T` as the common the x axis
The first plot contains `V1`
The second plot contains `V2`,`V3`,`V4`

I tried:

```
m1 <- melt(df, id = "T") 

chart1<-qplot(T, value, data = m1, geom = "line", group = variable) +
stat_smooth() +
facet_grid(variable ~ ., scale = "free_y")
```

But this gives me four common plots whereas I just want two.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Create a new factor in `m1`: `m1$sepfac <- (m1$variable=="V1")` and use it as your faceting variable.

Comment: Thanks very much. That's great.                       facet_grid(sepfac~., scale = "free_y")

Comment: It would be helpful if you can write up the solution and post it as an answer to your own question ... that makes it easier for future readers to see that the question has been successfully answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
library("reshape")

df <- data.frame(T,V1,V2,V3,V4)
m1 <- melt(df, id = "T") 

m1$sepfac <- (m1$variable=="V1")

chart1<-qplot(T, value, data = m1, geom = "line", group = variable) +
stat_smooth() +
facet_grid(sepfac~., scale = "free_y")
```